# How to allow user to join model by insertion of foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 4 with Devise authentication.

I have a one to many relationship between users and challenges. One user can have many challenges. There is a foreign key user_id in the challenges table.  At the moment this FK only gets populated with the user who created the challenge. However I would like other users to be able to join the challenge. This must be pretty simple as I'm sure it just involves inserting the foreign key of the user who wants to join into the challenges table. I'm not sure how to do this practically however.

I imagine it involves a user pressing a 'Join' button in a challenges view. That would then get routed to the join action in the challenge controller (which is like the update action ?is that correct) and it would pass the current user ID and the challenge I want to join ID. This would then update the database

```
def join
    respond_to do |format|
      if @challenge.update(challenge_params,:user_id => current_user.id)
        format.html { redirect_to @challenge, notice: 'You have joined.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @challenge }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: what i understand from the question, just give the button on the challenges index page for each challenge. clicking on that button will go to the join action in challenge controller and save the current_userid as user_id.

Comment: So is the join action I have written correct? and presumably the join button would carry both params as a link_to something like <td><%= link_to image_tag("list.jpg"), entries_path(challenge_id: challenge.id, :user_id => current_user.id), { class: "AllEntryLink", data: { remote: true } }  %></td>

Comment: yups i would make this `@challenge.update(challenge_params,:user_id => current_user.id)` simple. like this. at first i should do: `@challenge.user_id =  current_user.id` and then if `@challenge.save`

Comment: @Nermin has suggested inserting a new model UserChallenge. Why would this be useful- do you know- as opposed to your answer

Comment: if one challenge belongs to multiple user then you should have a seperate model `UserChallenge`. but if one challenge belongs to only one user. then you dont need that.. im not sure about your case.

Comment: Well I guess if many users can join a challenge then one user can have many challenges and one challenge can have many users so it ends up being many to many?

Comment: yes. this is the case of many to many relation. and in that case @Nermin has suggested right thing.

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine it involves a user pressing a 'Join' button in a challenges
>   view. That would then get routed to the join action in the challenge
>   controller (which is like the update action ?is that correct) and it
>   would pass the current user ID and the challenge I want to join ID.
>   This would then update the database

This is correct assumption, but you can not insert `user_id` in `challenges`, you have to create new model called `UserChallenge` and:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :challenges # you old association, created?
  has_many :user_challenges
  has_many :joined_challenges,  # list of all joined challenges
    through: :user_challenges,
    class_name: "Challenge"
  ...
end


class Challenged < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user # you old association
  has_many :user_challenges
  has_many :joined_users, # list of all joined users
    through: :user_challenges,
    class_name: "User"
  ...
end


class UserChallenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :challenge
  ...
end
```

Comment: OK. But why do I have to create another model? Also if I do create another model then how would I write the controller? And in fact which controller action would I use?

Comment: OK so I understand now as I'll be modelling a many to many relationship. However I still don't understand the path between pressing the join button and updating the db. Presumably the join button would send to the UserChallenge controller update action????

Comment: `create` action for `UserChallenge` controller, and you have to pass `user_id` and `challenge_id` that way user will join challenge